# Get the currently logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

How can I get the currently logged in user in SharePoint, I tried:

```
      SPUser user = null;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(@"siteName"))
        {

            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {

                user = web.CurrentUser;
            }
        }

  //and

  SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

  //and

   public SPUser GetUserWithElevated()
    {
        SPUser user = null;

        SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated elevatedSubmit = new 
        SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(delegate
        {

             user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
        });
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(elevatedSubmit);

        return user;
    }


  //this is my Httpmodule: 

   public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new 
   EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            // register handler for PreInit event
            page.PreInit += new EventHandler(page_PreInit);
        }
    }

    void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //user interception goes here}
```

I always get the system account, any solution?

Comment: From where are executing this code? From application page, Web part, console app or something else?

Comment: inside workflow i want to intercept the current user when he connect to mys site i do not know what is the right place in web part or....

Comment: actually i want to intercept that in HttpModule i want to add to my site

Comment: any help please

Comment: You should edit the question to reflect not only what you are doing but how you are trying to do it.  Also would be helpful to know how users login to SharePoint...i.e. Forms, Integrated, Claims, etc.

Comment: Try with simple web part and check if it is giving correct user.   SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

Comment: With Elevated privilege you will always get administrator or system account. So get current user outside it.

Answer (score 1):

So you mentioned a HttpModule in one of your comments.  `SPContext.Current.Web.User` will work in a SharePoint-deployed HttpModule as long as your module doesn't inspect the `SPContext` before `PreRequestHandlerExecute`...i.e. it won't be there in `BeginRequest` for example.

Assuming you're using integrated authentication the currently logged in user will also be in the `HttpContext`:

```
HttpContext context = (sender as HttpApplication).Context;
string userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
```

I've found that getting it from the `HttpApplication` (sender argument of event handler) is more universally reliable than `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: this is my Httpmodule: public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
        }

        void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                // register handler for PreInit event
                page.PreInit += new EventHandler(page_PreInit);
            }
        }

        void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { //here}